# can "mov ds,ax " be used to transfer 8bit data?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, memory-segmentation

I am studying mp book by the author-GODSE.
my question:

A) can AX,BX,CX,DX 16bit registers be used as source for transferring "8bit "data?
Ex: `Mov [734AH],BX`; copies "contents" of `bx` to `ds`.
Here, contents mean what?

- either data or word
- only word?

Ex2: `Mov DS,BX`; copies "word" from `bx` to `ds`.
Why they have mentioned word itself? (If 1 byte data can also be transferred, they would have given "content" itself.).

Comment: Are you talking about this book? http://books.google.com/books/about/Elements_Of_Microprocessors.html?id=8LqTavxvspwC

Answer (score 2):

> A) can AX,BX,CX,DX 16bit registers be used as source for transfering "8bit "data?

Not exactly. You can, however, use `AL` as a source for transferring 8 bits of data (specifically the low-order 8 bits of `AX`). `AX` itself holds 16 bits, and all of them are transferred if you use it as the source of a `MOV` instruction.

> Ex:Mov [734AH],BX; copies "contents" of bx to ds. Here,contents mean what? a)either data or word b)only word?

The "contents" are just that -- the contents of BX. The values of its 16 bits. They are transferred to the memory address given.

> Ex2: Mov DS,BX; copies "word" from bx to ds. Why they have mentioned word itself?

It sounds like you're confused about the meaning of "word." A [*word*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29) is a unit of data. To quote Wikipedia:

> A word is basically a fixed-sized group of digits (binary or decimal) that are handled as a unit by the instruction set or the hardware of the processor.

Comment: I think the confusion is that x86 uses `MOV` mnemonic to load from memory, store to memory, and in the case of `DS` load a segment register, amongst other uses of `MOV` lol.  So need to clarify that `MOV DS` is loading a segment register *not* storing to memory.

Comment: I read that word is a group of 16bis. They could commented as "contents of ax" in example2. Y they told as word? Suggest me exact answer. Can "mov ds,ax" be used for 8bit transfer?

Comment: The size of DS is 16 bits, too - same as AX. In the Intel x86 world, "word" means "16 bits". Even when talking about newer CPUs with 32 and 64-bit registers.

Comment: Can we copy 8 bit data using "mov ds,ax"? A)yes B)no.

Comment: @SHARVARI I think it has been pretty thoroughly explained that both DS and AX are 16-bit registers, and that therefore `mov ds, ax` copies 16 bits of data.

Answer (score 2):

In real mode; you can store whatever values you like in segment registers (e.g. `ds`), as long as you don't use unwanted values for memory references. For example, an instruction like `mov [foo],ax` uses `ds` as its implied segment register, and if you forget this and set `ds` to arbitrary values your code will break.

In protected mode and long mode; there are protection/sanity checks involved in segment register loads, and you can't store arbitrary values in segment registers. For most OSs (that use paging and don't use segmentation) its likely that there's only 2 values you can load into a data segment register like `ds` - the value it already contained when your process was started and zero.